# Add prerequisite on condition

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

Is it possible to add a prerequisite if another file is found in the workspace?  Or how else could I achieve the following idea?  Basically if my workspace has a lcf file in a specific location I need to make another file..  Something like this:

```
lcf := ../base_sw/lcf/base.lcf

.PHONY :
all : $(objects)

# if $(lcf) file exists then
all : $(objects) sup.a2l

sup.a2l :
    # Perl script runs here to produce sup.a2l
    @echo Chris > $@
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
lcf := $(wildcard ../base_sw/lcf/base.lcf)

.PHONY :
all : $(objects) $(lcf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've managed to answer this one myself!

The wildcard function returns nothing if lcf file does not exist:

```
  lcf := $(wildcard ../base_sw/lcf/base.lcf)
```

Start to build the files that need making:

```
make_these_file := $(obejcts)
```

If lcf variable is not empty, append to files list:

```
ifneq ($(lcf),)
   make_these_file += sup.a2l
endif
```

Now our target with files required to make:

```
.PHONY :
all : $(make_these_file)

sup.a2l :
   # Perl script here to produce sup.a2l
   @echo Chris > $@
```

Works for me :)